# How to test with Spek and Kluent

Tags: kotlin, mockito, spek

I have a simple Interface, but when I try to mock it my test fails. This is the error.

```
Mockito cannot mock this class: interface pmb.net.conn.types.INetworkLayer.

Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the 
mailing list.


Java               : 1.8
JVM vendor name    : Oracle Corporation
JVM vendor version : 25.0-b70
JVM name           : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
JVM version        : 1.8.0-b132
JVM info           : mixed mode
OS name            : Windows 8.1
OS version         : 6.3


Underlying exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an 
instance of declaring class
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Mockito cannot mock this class: interface pmb.net.conn.types.INetworkLayer.
```

This is the interface.

```kt
interface INetworkLayer {
    fun getDbStateHash(peerInfo: IPeerInfo): String
    fun getBlockMap(peerInfo: IPeerInfo, blockNumber: Int): IBlockMap
    fun getBlockPackages(blockNumber: Int, 
               packageIdsList: Iterable<String>): Iterable<BlockChunk>
}
```

This is part of my test code

```
describe("Description") {
    val peerInfoMock = mock(IPeerInfo::class)
    val networkLayerMock = mock(INetworkLayer::class)
    val peer = Peer(peerInfoMock, networkLayerMock)
```

Comment: What’s the `NetworkLayerMock`?

Comment: It is just the above interface, I dont have any implementation of it so far

Comment: If I remove the last function in the interface it works fine

Comment: Error description fixed

Comment: The title is a bit misleading, based on the exception the issue is with mockito. Are you using https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin?

Comment: Yes  Im using mockito